# How to calculate the combined current of all USB peripherals

Tags: macos, mac, usb, power

I recently purchased a (non-powered) USB 3.0 data hub with four ports.

When I had a cursory glance at the documentation that came with it, I saw it says connected devices should not exceed a combined current of 900mA.

I have connected:

- Keyboard
- USB-C cable (usually with Android device connected)
- USB flash drive
- DAW

The DAW has a current of 0.5A. The other items don't state it explicitly.

According to the guide in the hub instructions, it suggests a keyboard is usually rated at 500mA.

That seems quite high, but if correct would put the combined current over the total.

Is there a way I can calculate the combined current of all devices? Everything seems to be working fine.

I am using macOS 12.7.2.

Comment: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html check out this software.

Comment: Looks like it's only available for Windows.